# html-css make part of a div blur

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So, I'm learning HTML and CSS, and here's what I'm trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .floatdiv {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translateX(50%);
        text-align: center;
      }

      .basediv {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="basediv" id="particle">
      <!-- particles lives here -->
      <div class="floatdiv"><!-- some content --></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using this https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ and this is a minimal example of my actual code. I have some text content in the `floatdiv` that stays in the middle of the page and over the `basediv`. Now the `basediv` has the particles animation. Now what I want to do is to blur the particles animation just below the `flaotdiv`. I cant blur the `floatdiv`, that will make the content blurry, also I can't make the `basediv` blur, that would make the particles blur everywhere. So how do I blur only the background of the `floatdiv`

**Edit:** Well, Its maybe confusing, but I actually want, the particles to get blurred when it goes under the `floatdiv`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Could you clarify please, if you would want to make floatdiv background blurry without blurring the content OR blur the particles animation just below the floatdiv?

Comment: blur the particles just below the floatdiv

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, there is a way to solve this styling issue.

Instead of blur(), try using box-shadow method, as it would not blur the contents of `floatdiv`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Here is the example that might be helpful:

```css
.floatDivBlurred{
  transform: translateX(50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow:  0 0 8px 5px  green;
}


.floatDivBot{
  transform: translateX(50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 20px #99ff99;
}

.basediv{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="basediv" id="particle"> <!-- particles lives here -->  
    <div class="floatDivBlurred">
        <p><font color="white"> floatDiv blurred </font></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="floatDivBot">
        <p><font color="white"> floatDiv bottom blurred/extended </font></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, check the edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to ignore child element.

you need to change html markup like this

```
<div class="basediv"  style="position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;">
  <div id="particle" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:red; filter: blur(4px);z-index:-1;"> active particle js</div>
  <div class="floatdiv">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this blurs all the particles

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible if you apply **backdrop-filter: blur(4px)** and **-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px)** css property to **floatdiv**. It will blur everything underneath floatdiv's content while floatdiv's content will remain clear. However, this is not natively supported property on all browsers, in fact it's support is very limited (check the support tables here https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter).

Comment: As I mentioned, because of the limited support this currently works out-of-the-box only on safari and MS edge browsers. If you want it to work on chrome you have to enable experimental platform features through chrome:flags.